# onEditClick = {item.isEditing=true } not working as intended

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I encountered a problem: `onEditClick` is not working:
[image: description here]

I tried to fix it by using just one var eItem for edited items of the dataclass.

```
@Composable
fun all() {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var Items by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<GymContents>()) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = { showDialog = true },
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        ) {
            Text("Add Item")
        }
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            items(Items) { item ->
                list(
                    item = item,
                    onEditClick = { item.isEditing = true },
                    onDeleteClick = { Items = Items.filter { it.id != item.id } }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun list(
    item: GymContents, onEditClick: () -> Unit, onDeleteClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        IconButton(onClick = onEditClick) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Edit, contentDescription = null)
        }

        IconButton(onClick = onDeleteClick) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
}
```

So I guess that the problem is how i ve managed how to pass data from `edit()` to `all()`.

Comment: You need to paste all relevant code parts into your question, do not provide links to your code. Please only copy the *relevant* code parts, not the code in its entirety. You probably need to edit your code first to adhere to the guidelines layed out to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok modified hope that is fine now

Comment: That's still way too much irrelevant code. Can you please click the link I posted above and adhere to what it says? And please properly format your code before posting.

Comment: what do u think now?

Comment: There's something missing, it doesn't compile. And it isn't properly formatted. Please press CTRL+ALT+L in Android Studio.

Comment: cleanup code? optimize imports?

Comment: it does;'t compile cuz i removed some code.....

Comment: Seriously, have you read the link from my first comment? It should be *minimal*, as in "everything removed except the necessary parts" and *reproducible*, as in "can be executed and demonstrates the problem you experience". We cannot answer your question otherwise.

Comment: Hello @pizzamarinarasad, I edited your post. Your post should only contain the most relevant code to reproduce the issue, but at the same time, it has to be a well-formed code. You should not truncate your code by deleting closing brackets etc, please keep that in mind when posting question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can't / shouldn't modify an `item` directly in the `items` function of a `LazyColumn`. Instead, modify the `item` by modifying it in the `Items` list that you provided to the `items` function.

Please try the following code:

```
val Items = remember { mutableStateListOf<GymContents>() }
```

Then, update your `LazyColumn` as follows:

```
LazyColumn(
    //...
) {
    itemsIndexed(Items) { index, item ->
        list(
            item = item,
            onEditClick = { 
                // update the item
                Items[index] = Items[index].copy(isEditing = true)
            },
            //...
        )
    }
}
```

Note that you should have declared `GymContents` as a data class like this:

```
data class GymContents(
    val isEditing: Boolean,
    // other val properties
)
```

Comment: the data class is done correctly. if i copy paste the lazy column as u sent i get:Type mismatch: inferred type is List<GymContents> but Int was expected,Type mismatch: inferred type is LazyItemScope.(Int, Any?) -> Unit but LazyItemScope.(Int) -> Unit was expected,Expected one parameter of type Int,Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly,No set method providing array access,Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public inline operator (index: Int, value: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.text

Comment: I edited my answer, please check again.